# Заменить русские буквы на соответствующие английские в строке Swift

Tags: swift

Есть

```
var filename: String!
filename = "Это новое название строки"
```

Как трансформировать значение filename в newFilename? То есть заменить русские буквы соответствующими английскими, а пробел заменить на тире

```
 var newFilename: String!
 newFilename = "eto-novoe-nazvanie-stroki"
```

Comment: Не нужно использовать `T!` если между объявлением переменной и её инициализации нет использования переменной. `let filename: String;
filename = "Это новое название строки" — вполне работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно не изобретать свои велосипеды с заменой символов вручную и использовать [встроеную трансформацию строк](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablestring/string_transformations?language=swift):

```
func transliterate(nonLatin: String) -> String {
    return nonLatin
        .applyingTransform(.toLatin, reverse: false)?
        .applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)?
        .lowercased()
        .replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-") ?? nonLatin
}
```

Или используя библиотеку уровнем ниже, но в которой можно все правила трансформации задать сразу:

```
func transliterate(nonLatin: String) -> String {
    let mut = NSMutableString(string: nonLatin) as CFMutableString
    CFStringTransform(mut, nil, "Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; Any-Lower;" as CFString, false)
    return (mut as String).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-")
}
```

И в итоге будет:

```
transliterate(nonLatin: filename) // eto-novoe-nazvanie-stroki
```

Comment: спасибо. Попробую, отпишусь. Скажите, а если преобразовать в латиницу надо строку других языков и как игнорировать эмодзи и все знаки типа восклицательных, кавычек, скобок и пр. в переводе, если они используются в изначальной строке?

Comment: @StanislavPutilov, "Any-Latin" транслитерирует в латиницу все алфавиты, текущая реализация уже это может; для обратной транслитерации если что надо заменить правило на  "`Latin-Алфавит`"(`Latin-Cyrillic`, `Latin-Katakana` и т.д.) в строку правил; для удаления символов: "`Группа символов Remove`" (`[:Punctuation:] Remove`). Подробнее: http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать словарь соответствия

```
let dictionary: [Character: String] = [" ": "-", "а": "a", "б": "b", "в": "v", "я": "ya"]
```

И после использовать его для преобразования

```
var newFilename = ""
for char in filename {
    newFilename.append(dictionary[char] ?? String(char))
}
```

Comment: @StanislavPutilov А это сокращенное (по порядковому номеру) имя параметра замыкания. Кстати говоря, а символы "Я" или "Ж" в какие должены преобразоваться?

Comment: я нашел вот такой ряд замены rus = "щ   ш  ч  ц  ю  я  ё  ж  ъ  ы  э  а б в г д е з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ь"
`eng = "shh sh ch cz yu ya yo zh `` y' e` a b v g d e z i j k l m n o p r s t u f x `"

Comment: @StanislavPutilov Тогда предыдущий вариант не подойдет, потому как словарь типа `[Character: Character]`, а `Character` - это лишь один символ. Поправил сообщение, привёл другой вариант.

Comment: @StanislavPutilov, обычно сейчас `щ` транслитерируется как `sch` (а по старым более строгим правилам как `schsh`). И да, это вроде не соответствует ни одному из [стандартов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9), но такова реальность

Comment: @avp то есть sch, как в слове bosch?

Comment: @StanislavPutilov, по крайней мере `щ` в моей фамилии все носители языка пишут именно так -- Anischenko

Comment: @avp я помню свой первый загранпаспорт, там фамилия Путилов была Poutilov, типа на французский манер, так что всегда есть нюансы. Но спасибо за ремарку.

Comment: @StanislavPutilov, да, еще в СССР загран-документы в самом деле на французский манер писали, да и сейчас, например, у водительских прав аж 2 наименования (кроме русского) -- PERMIS DE   CONDUIRE и DRIVING LICENCE (но в них у меня Anishchenko)/ Хмм... может вам остановиться на **`shch`**?